# Sending an e-mail by decoded login

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, gmail

I have two scripts, the first one is designed to write down in two separated text files an e-mail address and a password (01.txt and 02.txt). A simple Caesar algorithm is used to hide them.
In the second script, I want to uncode the mail address and the password, and then send a mail.
It's weird because when I do that, I print the right log-in and password but it won't send anything, raising the error : SMTPAuthenticationError which is not true, because with my prints I see that I typed the right information which are rightly decoded. Do you have any lead ??

**mail_begin.py :**

```
def user():
    log = open("01.txt", "w")
    from_add = raw_input("Your mail address is : ")

    from_add = from_add.decode("utf-8")

    key = 3


    lettres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    lettres = lettres.decode("utf-8")

    crypted = ""


    for car in from_add:

        if car in lettres:

            num = lettres.find(car)

            num += key

            if num >= len(lettres):
                num = num - len(lettres)

            crypted += lettres[num]

        else:
            crypted += car

    log.write(crypted)
    log.close()

def password():

    log2 = open("02.txt", "w")
    passw2 = raw_input("Enter your password to log-in:")

    passw2 = passw2.decode("utf-8")

    key = 3


    lettres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    lettres = lettres.decode("utf-8")

    crypted = ""


    for car in passw2:

        if car in lettres:

            num = lettres.find(car)

            num += key

            if num >= len(lettres):
                num = num - len(lettres)

            crypted += lettres[num]

        else:
            crypted += car

    log2.write(crypted)
    log2.close()

user()
password()
```

**mail_finished.py**

```
import smtplib
import os
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart()
name = open("01.txt",'r')
passw = open("02.txt",'r')
f_l1 = str(name.readlines())
f_l2 = str(passw.readlines())

print (f_l1)
print (f_l2)

f_l1 = f_l1.decode("utf-8")
f_l2 = f_l2.decode("utf-8")
key = 3


lettres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
lettres = lettres.decode("utf-8")


decrypted = ""
decrypted2 =""

for car in f_l1:
    if car in lettres:
        num = lettres.find(car)

        num -= key

        if num < 0 :
            num = num + len(lettres)

        decrypted += lettres[num]
    else:
        decrypted += car

for car in f_l2:
    if car in lettres:
        num = lettres.find(car)

        num -= key

        if num < 0 :
            num = num + len(lettres)

        decrypted2 += lettres[num]
    else:
        decrypted2 += car

msg['From'] = str(decrypted)
msg['To'] = str(decrypted)

body = "Time to go back to the lab ! Your scan is over"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
print decrypted # e-mail clear
print decrypted2 # password clear
server.login(decrypted, decrypted2) # not working, bad authentification...
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(str(decrypted),str(decrypted), text)
server.quit()

name.close()
passw.close()

os.remove('01.txt')
os.remove('02.txt')
```

When everything is done, it erased the txt files so no one can decode them.
Could you try it at home, see where the problem is ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` return a list, by calling `str()` on the list you're generating a string representation of the list.

```
str(['mylist'])
```

is

```
"['mylist']"
```

instead, you should read only the line you want, using `readline` not `readlines` - it is already a string, no need to call `str()` all the time:

```
with open("01.txt") as f:
    name = f.readline().strip()

with open("02.txt") as f:
    password = f.readline().strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if I just modify :

```
f_l1 = (name.readlines())
f_l2 = (passw.readlines())
```

by

```
f_l1 = (name.readline())
f_l2 = (passw.readline())
```

it's working now. Thank you for your answer nosklo